# My Json post method is not working in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-post

I am trying to post some data to the web service using `JSON` `POST` method, I have tried so many ways to do this, but none is working. Here is my code, please check:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"subject", @"userID", @"message", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hi", @"57", @"i am ready",nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];

NSString *serverURL = @"http://xyzabc.com/web/IPAD/v1.0/webservices.php?type=Suggestions";
// Create the POST request to the server.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postdata];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

i am getting error message  Reply: {"status":0,"error":"Missing Subject (OR) message"} . please correct my code ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what u tried, can u show the correct url and what are the keys are used for send to server otherwise what the error u meet

Comment: Try to log the error.

Comment: Reply: {"status":0,"error":"Missing Subject (OR) message"}